# How do I set colorBufferWriteMask from Material Inspector

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

Im using "colorBufferWriteMask = []" to create a box that occludes part of the scene like a clipping mask. However, Im a bit new to this and I want to know if there is a way to use Xcodes material inspector to set a geometries matierial as such?

```
let occlusionMaterial = SCNMaterial()
occlusionMaterial.colorBufferWriteMask = []

geometry.materials = [occlusionMaterial]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First on the bottom of Material Inspector you can see 'Write to color' with options red, blue, green and alpha ticked. Untick all of them. This creates a transparent material. Or there is 'Transparency' just under 'Settings'. Change it's mode to 'RGB Zero' and value to 1.

Now go to Node Inspector and under 'Visibility' you will see 'Rendering Order' with value 0. Set it to -1 (the idea is to set this order lower than object's that gets occluded behind it)

You can see the objects behind the node with this settings will be invisible.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!